# android custom theme divider color for listview

Tags: android

I have designed a custom theme for the activity.Everything seems to be applying fine to the views except divider color for listview.(android:dividercolor attribute).

I applied it along with android:dividerheight attribute as suggested in other threads.divider height also applied correctly.

But when i apply divider color through activity xml file for the specific listview,custom color was applied correctly.

Can't we apply custom divider color from custom theme?

Comment: @qbix,it worked.I tried it today.Thank you :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `android:dividercolor`, use `android:listDivider`.

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Some.Base.Theme">
    <item name="android:listDivider">@color/my_divider_color</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">4dp</item>
</style>
```